# How to show that $\prod_{k=1}^{t\cdot \sqrt n}(1-\frac{k}{n}) \to e^\frac{-t^2}{2}, \ \ n\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show that $$\prod_{k=1}^{t\cdot \sqrt n}(1-\frac{k}{n}) \to e^\frac{-t^2}{2}, \ \ n\to \infty$$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried  Rieman sum, but  limit of the product depends on n.

Comment: This product is exactly $$\frac{(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdots(n-t\sqrt{n})}{n\cdot n\cdots n}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-t\sqrt{n}-1)!\cdot n^{t\sqrt{n}}}$$now use Stirling's approximation for example to get the required result.

Comment: @Anton write your tries in the body of the question, otherwise, the question will probably get some downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

$$P_n=\prod_{k=1}^{t\,\sqrt n}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\implies \log(P_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{t\,\sqrt n}\log\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)$$

Now, using Taylor series for large values of $n$
$$\log\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)=-\frac{k}{n}-\frac{k^2}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\log(P_n)=-\frac 12 t^2-\frac{t \left(t^2+3\right)}{6\sqrt n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$P_n=e^{\log(P_n)}\to \exp\left(-\frac {t^2}2 \right)$$

Answer (score 2):

1. For $P>0 \ P = e^{\log P}$, so you can rewrite your expression
2. $\log (1-x) \sim -x \ $if $x \to 0$, this is Taylor series expansion.
   Now you can take the limit as $n \to \infty$ and get the result.

For 2), to be more thorough, you can instead use lower and upper bounds on Taylor series expansion for $\log$, and take the limit as $n \to \infty$, the result will be the same.